# No option to update new version of Android application

Tags: android

I have published new version of Android application to play store. But I do not have 'update' button for updating from previous version. I have only 2 options 'Open' and 'Uninstall'.

For new version I need to uninstall existing and then download new version. I am generating signed APK and using the same key. I have also changed the version code and version name.

Is there anything I need to add in code for autoupdate? I need to avoid uninstalling everytime I have new version of application published to play store. Please give me any solution if you have.

Answer (score 2):

When did you push the app? It may take several hours before it's live. The Play Developer Console should provide some info on when the rollout is available. It may be possible to specify a rollout time when the update will be live.

If you have been debugging the app on your phone, and the version code is the same as on your phone or your app is the debug signature, you won't be asked to update.

Comment: I pushed it 2 days back and new version is available now in play store. But if I have previous version installed it does not give an option to update. Instead I have to uninstall and install new version from play store again.

Comment: @Kavita, check installed version on your device and in project. I think you have as developer it updated by testing of app

Comment: Nick is right, the app installed on the pretense of testing will not be updated automatically by the Play Services.

Comment: @SanVed Now the app is in alpha and beta testing. I just want to make clear, is it only the application which is released to Production will have the option of update? If it is in alpha or beta testing then we need uninstall and install again?

Comment: If the app on your device has the same signature (ie. the signed APK) and the version on your device is lower than the Play Store, you should see an update regardless of beta or alpha testing.

My guess is your APK signature is different on your device compared to the version in Google Play.

Comment: @NickFelker I am generating APK using the same key and publishing app to play store. And I have different set of alpha and beta users who download it every time from play store. But for every new version they need to uninstall and install again from play store.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the version code and version name in your **gradle file of app module** 
I think you changed version code in manifest file instead of gradle file.or you changed version in wrong gradle file

Comment: I changed in grade file itself.

Comment: can u add your code and a picture of your packages?